# Jupyter with Python3: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When trying to plot something in my notebook, I get this error message:

> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

For instance, simple code like this fails:

```
 %pylab inline 
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 import numpy as np
 plt.plot(np.sin(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 100)))
```